# rolling back apex process code from another page

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I have two Pages Like 10 and 11 from the Page 11 i have process on button which is updating the tables back in database and after processing user back to page 10, So in any case i want to rollback the changes done on page 11 process or may have to save on page 10 by using a button to make changes permanent on Page 10.

I have tried by running ROLBACK on page 11 but it doesnt work as Apex did a implicit commit on page 11 so i can not get any thing from rollback.

I actually want to make changes permanent only from page 11 not from page 10 Please suggest the way how i can achieve this,

Answer (score 0):

One option might be using (global) temporary tables (GTT) whose description would be the same as the ones you currently use in Page 11 process.

Doing so, you'd commit changes on GTT (make sure they are created using the `on commit preserve rows` option). Then, when you are redirected to Page 10, either

- propagate changes to "real" tables (if you choose to keep those changes)
- clear GTT and do nothing to "real" tables (if you choose to discard changes)

Comment: I have huge Code with More than 6 Tables which are being populated in Sequence as First Table is Mast are Second is Detail of First and Third is detail of Second and fourth is Detail of Third and so on with lot of conditions so its very hard to Once copy data from real tables to GTT for edit and then back to actual tables to save changes , so i am expecting something commit and rollback simply

Comment: Any Update on above Concern?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.